# Join a table for every match of values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I wanna join them. There is one value artist_IDs, which stores all artist IDs for that album. I wanna to get all artists data of that album but I can't get it to work, because Locate doesn't work and neither is Like. Do u have any idea how I can achieve this in MySQL with MariaDB?

```
SELECT artists.name,artists.ID from artists WHERE LOCATE(artists.ID,"2Im8m4STDBosjfmb5hmP80,1pkDzgHvVqC17qYGKfLPpb")
```

This query like how I want it to have. It returns two artists because there are two IDs given. But it doesnt work in my needed statement:

```
SELECT albums.ID, albums.name, albums.imageID,artists.name as artistsname FROM albums INNER JOIN (SELECT artists.name,artists.ID from artists) artists ON LOCATE(artists.ID,albums.artist_IDs) GROUP BY albums.ID
```

[image]

Thats what I get but I want, for the album where name= No Richt Parents two entries. One with the artistsname Mozzik and the other one with the artistsname Loredana because their IDs are stored in the albums.artists_IDs field.

Here u can download the two tables: [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Mx-xHEwhYMoiSsCbXMWrvmKGYaHVsDmC?usp=sharing)

Comment: *But it doesnt work in my needed statement* Provide online fiddle or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts with sample data and point us to the output incorrectness.

Comment: I did update my question, I hope thats better ;)

Comment: No, this is not "better" - nobody can copy your data into the table and reproduce your issue. The scripts I have told above must be code-formatted SQL text available for copying.

Comment: Okay I added the files for the two tables

Comment: Next time provide your data as a fiddle (like in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use aggregate function, hence only one (indefinite) value for a group is returned. You must aggregate your data.

```sql
-- your second query, fixed version
SELECT albums.ID, albums.name, albums.imageID, GROUP_CONCAT(artists.name) as artistsname 
FROM albums 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT artists.name, artists.ID 
             FROM artists) artists ON LOCATE(artists.ID, albums.artist_IDs) 
GROUP BY albums.ID
```

```
-- more clear code
SELECT albums.ID, albums.name, albums.imageID, GROUP_CONCAT(artists.name) AS artistsname 
FROM albums 
INNER JOIN artists ON LOCATE(artists.ID, albums.artist_IDs) 
GROUP BY albums.ID, albums.name, albums.imageID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=aa20427202459a732f4c5e86315a32f2

---

PS. Do not disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL server mode.

Comment: thank u very much <3

Comment: is there also a way, not to combine them with a comma, but to have them in the result table as two different rows? That would be nice, but I could do this in php as well.

Comment: @Tom Simply remove GROUP BY and aggregate function... `SELECT albums.ID, albums.name, albums.imageID, artists.name AS artistname FROM albums 
INNER JOIN artists ON LOCATE(artists.ID, albums.artist_IDs)`.